# Jenkins pipeline top-level join gets triggered before sub-level join

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I've got a multi-level build pipeline with a "top-level" join (`test_Join`) and a "sub-level" join (`test_Build1_Join`) (see image below).

My `test_Join` job requires artifacts from both `test_Build1_Join` and `test_Build2`. I copy them by filtering on a parameter named `PL_BUILD_NUMBER` that's passed downstream from `test_Start` job. That works (see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795161))

**My problem is**
Sometimes, the "top-level" join is triggered *before* the "sub-level" join, like in the image below. This mean that the build artifacts are not yet available and I get the following error:

```
Copied 1 artifact from "test_Build2" build number 33
Unable to find a build for artifact copy from: test_Build1_Join
Build step 'Copy artifacts from another project' marked build as failure
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Finished: FAILURE
```

The joins are done using the "Join Trigger" plugin, with the "run post-build actions at join -> Trigger parameterized build on other projects" options.

How can I synchronise the whole pipeline better? What's the standard practice?

[image: Two joins in build pipeline]

Comment: Did you tried Multi Job Plugin?