# How to trigger multiple jobs programmatically in Jenkins

Tags: java, spring-boot, jenkins, command-line-interface, jenkins-cli

I need to trigger all the jobs in a specific view programmatically and connect it to a Spring Boot controller class. The jobs are in my local Jenkins.

I read the links, but it can only trigger one job at a time. I have like 50 jobs in my Jenkins. how do I trigger all at once.

I cannot edit all the jobs from the job config and then execute it, so I need another way, maybe from Jenkins CLI, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins/Hudson - How to run multiple jobs in parallel more than 1 level deep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366167/jenkins-hudson-how-to-run-multiple-jobs-in-parallel-more-than-1-level-deep)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use groovy and `scheduleBuild2`. This to [trigger the build - waitPeriod 0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63405325/598141)

This should work...

```
Jenkins.instance.getView('<VIEW>').items.each() {
    it.scheduleBuild2(0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can trigger jobs programmatically by using a command: java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8082/ -auth : build