# How can I cause a multi-config jenkins job to fail if one or more _multiple jobs_ are all not successful?

Tags: jenkins

I need to run a jenkins job, but it must fail if 5 other jobs are all successful. It needs to fail or refuse to run unless all five of its upstream jobs have the 'success' status.

This is a multi-configuration job and I need the check to run on the master before it branches off to multiple slaves.

Therefore, I need something that would enable me to, upon firing this particular multi-configuration job off, check its five upstream jobs for success or failure, and if one of them is not successful, fail before the job splits off into its multiple slave runs.

EDIT: **TO BE CLEAR**, I am not asking for a *trigger*. I am asking for a way to make the job *fail* if certain other jobs are not green (i.e., their last runs were successful). I cannot do this as a build step because it is a multi-configuration job and I'd rather not have the different configurations each check themselves before they run.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012310/how-do-i-make-a-jenkins-job-start-after-multiple-simultaneous-upstream-jobs-succ) which is similar. I would also look at [Script Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ScriptTrigger+Plugin) that will allow you to poll the jobs you want with a script, which can check for their status.