# Jenkins - Wait for the manual step to finish in parallel with some automatic job

Tags: jenkins, deployment, continuous-integration, delivery-pipeline

I'm trying to build the above 'delivery pipeline' using Jenkins.

[image]

Every job excluding "Manual Step" will run when upstream jobs end with success. My problem is that I cannot do 'join' 
between the two jobs (run "Manual Step" and "Auto Step" in parallel and wait for the 2 to finish sucessfully before "Final Step"). 
Is there any way to make this possible with Jenkins? Maybe some plugin?

This question is very similar to this one: [How do I make a Jenkins job start after multiple simultaneous upstream jobs succeed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012310/how-do-i-make-a-jenkins-job-start-after-multiple-simultaneous-upstream-jobs-succ)

But what I really want is to know if it is possible to parallelize two different types of jobs (jobs who run manually and jobs who run automatically).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's been a time since I posted the question and it seems there is no elegant solution to the problem I'm going to share my work-around:

**First**, I edited the two jobs so that a new file is created whenever the Manual and Automatic Jobs finish successfully (1 file for each job).

**Next**, I put a validation on the 'Final Step' job to only run if the two files are created. If the two files are created, proceeds to the 'Final Step' job instructions