# Jenkins: Triggering Maven Release manually in Build Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, maven-release-plugin, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2, delivery-pipeline

I got a problem with my Jenkins (1.6) setup and so far haven't found a solution.

**What I want to do:**

I have 4 Jobs (StartJob, TestA, TestB, ReleaseJob) and I'd like to have a "pipeline", that says:

- Start with "StartJob"
- After that, build "TestA" and "TestB" in parallel
- When *both* "TestA" *and* "TestB" have finished, let me manually trigger the ReleaseJob

**What I have tried so far**

I'm using the  [Delivery Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Delivery+Pipeline+Plugin) to be able to get a nice pipeline view and to be able to set manual triggers that you can simply define in the Post-Build Actions. This worked pretty well so far.

My first attempt at this was using the [Join Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Join+Plugin), which simply did not work at all. It always triggered the last build at once - no matter if "TestA" and "TestB" were actually successful.

For my second attempt I used the [Multijob Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) and defined 2 Phases: The first included only "StartJob" and the second included "TestA" and "TestB". After that I defined the "ReleaseJob" as manual trigger in the Post-build Actions. This worked ok, but I'm not at the point that if I trigger the "ReleaseJob", it will not run it as a "Maven Release".

**My Questions**

- Is there a way to force a "Maven Release" job to be build as a "Maven Release"? (i.e. you shouldn't be able to simply use the "Build now" function)
- Do you have any suggestions as to how I could solve this problem in a different way?

**Additional Note:**

I have not yet used the new Pipeline system in Jenkins 2 - I only just set it up for a small test. If you don't know a solution for the old Jenkins but know how to set it up as a "coded pipeline" in Jenkins 2, I'd be very interested in that as well.

Thanks a lot and cheers,

/tehK

Answer (score 1):

I think the precursor to the Pipline plugin is the Buildflow plugin which I don't see you mention having tried. There is an example in this other SO thread:

[How do I make a Jenkins job start after multiple simultaneous upstream jobs succeed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012310/how-do-i-make-a-jenkins-job-start-after-multiple-simultaneous-upstream-jobs-succ)

Maybe this will give you some insight into how to use it

Answer (score 0):

I know your question is 2 years old, but since I am wondering if you ever found a solution...

Did you try using an **HTTP Post** in your **Post-build Actions** to trigger the [M2-Release-Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/M2+Release+Plugin) on the Jenkins job?  That was my [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39605276/trigger-perform-maven-release-of-a-jenkins-job-from-another-job/40980718#40980718) since [this task](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29519) is probably not going to be completed by the Jenkins team in the short term.